# Can non-Western characters be used in HTML "name" attribute?

Tags: php, html

In an HTML `<input>`:

Is it an obligation to set `name` attribute with English characters?

I want to use it later, in `$_POST['some_utf8_characters_and_not_english_characters']`.

Is it possible to cause a problem later?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'English characters'? Do you mean Latin/Western script?

Comment: In theory, no, but I don't trust PHP enough to make that an answer.

Comment: Specifically, I want to use "persian" characters. Before asked this question, I'd been thought like Quentin, but I want to know is there anyone who has more accurate answer to this question?

Comment: @peterneok: This is not a practice! I want to program a website in other language (other than English), so If my indexes were similar to my values, it will be better for me.

Comment: as of [HTML4's specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#adef-name-INPUT), the name attribute corresponds to "CDATA" which `is a sequence of characters from the document character set and may include character entities.`. In a HTML point of view, it's actually valid. Now, I won't trust PHP on this, I'd made some tests.

Comment: @Shikiryu PHP is more trustable than you'd think, you just need to understand what you're doing. :)

Comment: @deceze I trust what I test or what I see, not what I (or anyone) *think* will work. That's why I said that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to RFC1866 chapter 3.2.4, an attribute's value can be anything except the value delimiter (single or double quote), and shouldn't contain HTML tag delimiters (< and >).

However, you'll have to test how JavaScript behaves on all browsers (remember your great friend MSIE...) when you try to access a DOM element using `name` as references. For example: `document.anElementWithPersianName` or `document.forms['aFormWithAPersianName']`. So if you use JS to validate, and/or ajax to submit a form, you'll need to be sure that JS is able to handle this character set properly.

In any case, you'll have to ensure that:

1. your PHP scripts use UTF-8-based functions when it's about string manipulation (I think some functions need to have the charset passed as an argument)
2. these scripts are themselves saved in UTF-8 files
3. you correctly set the character set in the HTML header and/or PHP's response header

Best thing to do: create a simple form, do some JS tricks on it, and have a PHP script parse the submitted results and print them.

Answer (score 0):

This is successfully working in one of my websites. No problems.

```
<input name="UTF_word" />

$_POST['UTF_word']
```

Both does not give any problems in client side, including jquery (not checked in IE) or server side.